# How should I reconnect an outlet where a ceiling fan circuit comes in?

Tags: electrical

I’ve been replacing the receptacles in my house with new ones after I paint each room and so far it hasn’t been a problem. Today I went to replace the three in the living room and now I can’t get the power to work to any of the outlets on this circuit. Two were normal black and white wires so I’m assuming those were done properly, but this one powers a ceiling fan, and it has a red and three white plus three black wires tied off. I can’t figure out how to connect it all to the receptacle for the power to work. I would think the power would still work at the other outlets but clearly this one connects the whole circuit and I don’t know how to wire it

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80939/discussion-on-question-by-erica-how-should-i-reconnect-an-outlet-where-a-ceilin).